# Set refind as default boot loaader on a mac. ( Having trouble saving bless settings )

Tags: linux, macos, boot, arch-linux

I have done quite a bit net surfing and have not been able to find a solution to my problem.

Here is the background info:

1. The refind boot loader is installed to my EFI partition on the mac (sda1)
2. Have no problem booting either Mountain lion or Arch
3. After blessing the drive in OSX and rebooting, it loads the correct boot loader and will continue to do so as long as I continue to only boot Arch. The first time I boot OSX from refind and reboot, the boot loader defaults back to OSX.

After installing arch I logged into OSX, mounted the EFI boot partition to /Volumes/esp, I blessed the partition with,

sudo bless --mount /Volumes/esp --setBoot --file /Volumes/esp/efi/refind/refind_x64.efi

I checked the output of "bless --info" and everything was correct. As stated, everything works as expected until I boot OSX from the selection menu. Does anyone know how I can make these setting save? I know I can write a script to run on shutdown but that seems unnecessary since I am sure there is a way to save these settings. Any help is greatly appreciated.

( not sure if this helps but refind was installed to the EFI partition driectly from arch install. )

Thanks,